# AnimateWithDuration disables userInteraction on UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, frame, childviewcontroller, animatewithduration

I'm adding a child view on top of one of my views, and animating it so that it starts at the bottom of the screen and ends up at the top of the screen by using animateWithDuration. And that all works fine except that after **animateWithDuration** is complete the view on top has no user interaction and the view below still has user interaction. If I remove **animateWithDuration**, and just start the child view at it's normal position the user interaction works how I would expect it too, which is why I think **animateWithDuration** is the problem.

**Here's my code:**

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[CCouponDetailViewController alloc] init];
[[viewController view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * -1), viewController.view.bounds.size.width, viewController.view.bounds.size.height)];
[self addChildViewController:viewController];
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

CGRect newFrame = viewController.view.frame;
newFrame.origin.x = 0;
newFrame.origin.y = ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * -1);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
     animations:^{
         viewController.view.frame = newFrame;
     }
     completion:^(BOOL finished){
         [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
     }
];
```

Another question I have (Not really important just curious) is that in newFrame I'm setting the y to the same thing as it is when I initially set the bounds, but yet it moves. I would have expected newFrame to require a y value of "0" but when I did that nothing happened. Just wondering why that is.

Comment: OK, this is actually a very complicated answer to explain... but I'm working on it now. It's just taking a second to get the wording right so you can understand it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll actually go backwards on this one...

*"Another question I have (Not really important just curious) is that in newFrame I'm setting the y to the same thing as it is when I initially set the bounds, but yet it moves. I would have expected newFrame to require a y value of "0" but when I did that nothing happened. Just wondering why that is."*

This is actually a very important question for you to have answered, because it has a lot to do with why your code isn't working. You're misunderstanding some very important concepts.

First off, the `bounds` of a `UIView` determine its position entirely in relation to itself. The `frame` determines the `UIView`'s position within its superview. In your code, you're originally setting the view's `bounds`, not the `frame` --

```
[[viewController view] setBounds:CGRectMake(0, ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * -1), viewController.view.bounds.size.width, viewController.view.bounds.size.height)];
```

-- so you're not at all originally determining the view's place within its superview, only in relation to itself.

Essentially, you're ending up with a `CCouponDetailViewController` view with a 0x0 frame, but since you haven't specified that you want your `UIView` to clip its subviews, the portions of your `CCouponDetailViewController` view are not actually on top of their view, but visible and hanging over the `UIView`'s bounds. The reason they aren't selectable is because they're not actually within the `UIView`.

So to fix this, set your `UIView`'s initial *frame* instead of setting a *bounds* (I've editing the initial frame to start at the bottom of the screen like you're trying to do. I don't understand the height x -1 thing you're trying to do, by the way...) :

```
[[viewController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, viewController.view.bounds.size.width, viewController.view.bounds.size.height)];
```

Secondly, you're setting your new frame incorrectly. You can't set the CGRect this way:

```
CGRect newFrame = viewController.view.frame;
newFrame.origin.x = 0;
newFrame.origin.y = ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height * -1);
```

Instead, set it using `CGRectMake` (And, again, I edited the y value so that the view ends up at the top of the screen like you're trying to do):

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, viewController.view.frame.width, viewController.view.frame.height);
```